# Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp... (Accesing Object Array Value )

Tags: php, arrays

`$result` is

```
stdClass Object
(
    [cityId] => 000000000020
    [checkInDate] => 2013-12-20
    [checkOutDate] => 2013-12-21
    [customerId] => 
    [customerAccountType] => SH01
    [customerType] => 
    [currency] => INR
    [noOfRoomsRequested] => 1
    [searchAvailabilityResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [hotelId] => IXW1
            [hotelName] => Ginger Jamshedpur
            [Rate] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [rateId] => STANDARD
                    [rateVersion] => 
                    [contractId] => 
                    [contractVersion] => 000
                    [allocationId] => IBE
                    [perPaxRateTypeSet] => 
                    [taxInclusiveInRateFlag] => 
                    [price] => 3499
                    [offerPrice] => 3499
                    [packageCost] => 0
                    [taxAmount] => 0
                    [luxuryTax] => 437.38
                    [serviceTax] => 216.24
                    [offerPercentageDiscount] => 0
                    [offerIdentifier] => 
                    [displayType] => 
                    [rateIdentifierType] => STANDARD
                    [rateIdTypeDesc] => STANDARD RATE
                    [conceptIdentifier] => ONLYROOM
                    [packageIdentifier] => 
                    [smartRate] => 
                    [roomGrid] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [room] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [roomNumber] => 1
                                            [roomType] => TWN
                                            [pricingType] =>  
                                            [numOfPax] => 1
                                            [numberOfAdults] => 1
                                            [numberOfChildren] => 0
                                            [numberOfJuniors] => 0
                                            [numOfPaxForWhichRateApplied] => 1
                                            [numOfpaxStaying] => 0
                                            [conceptId] => ONLYROOM
                                            [isAlternative] => 
                                            [packageCost] => 0
                                            [taxAmount] => 0
                                            [luxuryTax] => 437.38
                                            [serviceTax] => 216.24
                                            [dayWiseRate] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [forDay] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [date] => 2013-12-20
                                                            [price] => 3499
                                                            [offerPrice] => 3499
                                                            [taxAmount] => 0
                                                            [luxuryTax] => 437.38
                                                            [serviceTax] => 216.24
                                                            [availability] => 42
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [roomNumber] => 1
                                            [roomType] => STD
                                            [pricingType] =>  
                                            [numOfPax] => 1
                                            [numberOfAdults] => 1
                                            [numberOfChildren] => 0
                                            [numberOfJuniors] => 0
                                            [numOfPaxForWhichRateApplied] => 1
                                            [numOfpaxStaying] => 0
                                            [conceptId] => ONLYROOM
                                            [isAlternative] => 1
                                            [packageCost] => 0
                                            [taxAmount] => 0
                                            [luxuryTax] => 437.38
                                            [serviceTax] => 216.24
                                            [dayWiseRate] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [forDay] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [date] => 2013-12-20
                                                            [price] => 3499
                                                            [offerPrice] => 3499
                                                            [taxAmount] => 0
                                                            [luxuryTax] => 437.38
                                                            [serviceTax] => 216.24
                                                            [availability] => 21
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [policies] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [policy] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [policyType] => ADV
                                            [policyCode] => ADVIXW1001
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [policyType] => CAN
                                            [policyCode] => CNXIXW1002
                                        )

                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [policyType] => AMD
                                            [policyCode] => AMDIXW1002
                                        )

                                    [3] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [policyType] => NOS
                                            [policyCode] => NSIXW1002
                                        )

                                    [4] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [policyType] => CCP
                                            [policyCode] => CIOIXW1001
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

i want to access  `[rateIdTypeDesc] => STANDARD RATE`

what i tried

```
foreach ($result->searchAvailabilityResult->Rate as $item)
{

echo $item->rateIdTypeDesc; echo "<hr>";


}


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($result->searchAvailabilityResult->Rate as $key=>$item) {
  if($key == 'rateIdTypeDesc'){
    echo $item;
  }
}
```